# C language: Macro calling from main return strange error

Tags: c

So i have to write `Macro` that checks `array` of `numbers` and return the `number` of `numbers` that there left `bits` is `1` equal to right `bits` is `1`.

For example: `10110111`

So this is my `Macro`:

```
#define check(arr, count, result)\
{\
 int i,half,bitloop1,bitloop2,bitcount;\
bitcount-0;\
i=0;\
half=(sizeof(int)*8)\2;\
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)\
{\
    bitcount = 0;\
    bitloop1=0;\
    bitloop2=0;\
    unsigned int mask = 1 << (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1);\
    while (mask)\
    {\
        bitcount++;\
        if ((arr[i]&mask) == 1)\
        {\
            if(bitcount<half-1)\
                bitloop1++;\
            else\
                bitloop2++;\
        }\
        mask >>= 1;\
    }\
    if(bitloop1==bitloop2)\
        result++;\
}\
}
```

**Main**

```
int arr[] = { 183, 12 };
int result = 0;
check(arr, 2, result);
printf("%d", result);
```

So my check `Macro` in the main return errors:

```
unrecognized token
illegal escape sequence
syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant'
```

Comment: Clarify the question.

Comment: What cause this errors..

Comment: The compiler complains about this part "half=(sizeof(int)*8)\2;\" Do you want to divide by 2 ? In that case use "half=(sizeof(int)*8)/2;\"

Comment: Why on earth would you write a function that big as a macro?  Macros have their uses.  I'm very far from convinced that this a macro that justifies itself.  You should make it a function — you could try making it `static inline` if you want macro-like properties — and debug it as a function, not a macro.

Comment: this will check a single number: `#define check( value )  ((value)&0x01 && (value)&(1<<(sizeof(int)-1))`  invoke that in a loop with a counter to obtain the desired result

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two typos:

1. `bitcount-0;\`should be `bitcount=0;\`
2. `half=(sizeof(int)*8)\2;\` should be `half=(sizeof(int)*8)/2;\`

Comment: the typo fixed but still same errors

Comment: @DannyNitman: If you fixed these two errors, you won't get the same compilation errors.  Indeed, when compiled without those errors, the program runs and reports `1`.  So, revisit whether you actually fixed them.  Then rewrite the macro as a function — it's very silly to use a macro for this.

Answer (score 0):

it is very poor programming practice to write a function as a macro.

Suggest:

```
#define check( value )  ((value)&0x01 && (value)&(1<<(sizeof(int)-1))

int result = 0;
for( size_t i=0; i<(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); i++ )
{
    result += check( array[i] );
}
printf( "%d\n", result );
```